# Shell passing complex json alters it

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

So I have the problem where passing complex json might be altered by moving it with shell.

```
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SelectedAnimeMedia);
                Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"MediaDetailsPage?name={json}");
```

SelectedAnimeMedia is object of my class

```
public class Media
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string BannerImage { get; set; }
        public int? AverageScore { get; set; }
        public int Favourites { get; set; }
        public int? Episodes { get; set; }
        public airingSchedule airingSchedule { get; set; }
        public MediaScheduleNode nextAiringEpisode { get; set; }
        public ListEntry mediaListEntry { get; set; }
        public TitleType Title { get; set; }
        public CoverImageType CoverImage { get; set; }
        public Date startDate { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to serialize to pass it with that shell method. This is what I pass

```
"{\"Id\":129898,\"Description\":\"The world's number one assassin has been reincarnated as the eldest son of a family of aristocrat assassins. In exchange for being reincarnated in another world, a goddess has imposed upon him one condition. \\\"Kill the Hero who is prophesied to destroy the world.\\\" <br>\\n<br>\\nThis was to be the mission in his new life. The synergistic effect of the vast knowledge and experience he gained that made all manner of assassinations possible in the modern world, and the secret techniques and magic of the fantasy world's most powerful family of assassins turn him into the greatest assassin of all time.<br>\\n<br>\\n(Source: Crunchyroll)\",\"BannerImage\":null,\"AverageScore\":null,\"Favourites\":253,\"Episodes\":null,\"airingSchedule\":null,\"nextAiringEpisode\":null,\"mediaListEntry\":null,\"Title\":{\"Romaji\":null,\"English\":null,\"Native\":null,\"UserPreferred\":\"The World's Finest Assassin Gets Reincarnated in Another World as an Aristocrat\"},\"CoverImage\":{\"Medium\":null,\"Large\":\"https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/medium/bx129898-FRUzDtPhRigt.jpg\"},\"startDate\":null}"
```

This is what is received:

```
"{\"Id\":129898,\"Description\":\"The world's number one assassin has been reincarnated as the eldest son of a family of aristocrat assassins. In exchange for being reincarnated in another world, a goddess has imposed upon him one condition. /\"Kill the Hero who is prophesied to destroy the world./\" <br>/n<br>/nThis was to be the mission in his new life. The synergistic effect of the vast knowledge and experience he gained that made all manner of assassinations possible in the modern world, and the secret techniques and magic of the fantasy world's most powerful family of assassins turn him into the greatest assassin of all time.<br>/n<br>/n(Source: Crunchyroll)\",\"BannerImage\":null,\"AverageScore\":null,\"Favourites\":253,\"Episodes\":null,\"airingSchedule\":null,\"nextAiringEpisode\":null,\"mediaListEntry\":null,\"Title\":{\"Romaji\":null,\"English\":null,\"Native\":null,\"UserPreferred\":\"The World's Finest Assassin Gets Reincarnated in Another World as an Aristocrat\"},\"CoverImage\":{\"Medium\":null,\"Large\":\"https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/medium/bx129898-FRUzDtPhRigt.jpg\"},\"startDate\":null}"
```

Please copy and paste it in your notepad. Notice messed up slashes which unables me to deserialize it. Especially in Description field, but they are wrong in whole json.

I can do this `Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new MediaDetailsPage(selectedAnimeMedia));`

But what is the difference between this and the string based one? Is this method also pushing on Shell stack? As it isn't mentioned NOWHERE in the docs, which is weird. It doesn't require me to register route. And I don't know If I should use it or will it cause me problems on the line

What would be the correct way to just pass data having such complex strings with Shell? Or maybe I should not use strings.

Comment: querystring is usually intended for simple types, not complex json that will break the encoding scheme

Comment: Should I use the method I described at the end? Pass object there and then to view model? I don't know why it is not explained at all in the docs. And what will be the ultimate difference in navigation and what happens behind

Comment: Decompose your object into multiple query parameters. You're putting too much under the `name` query parameter, and Shell is trying to encode that data to pass it without breaking the route string format.

Comment: This would work with more simple objects. What if I get a list of objects that are made of three strings? It might be a small one but might be a large one

Comment: What about making a local database perhaps? And send a string that will allow me to identify the right object, or is that a huge waste of time just to pass an object between the pages?

Comment: This link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases) may help you to use the local database.